# Facebook pass flashvars to swf?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, facebook

Im trying to get the facebook username set to a flashvars and then pass it to a swf, like so:

```
var flashvars = {
      AppID: "my_id",
      Name: ""
      };

  function init()
  {
    FB.init({appId:APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(handleLoginStatus);
  }

  function handleLoginStatus(response)
  {
    if (response.session) { //Show the SWF
          FB.api('/me/', function(response){  alert(response.name); flashvars['Name'] = response.name;});
      swfobject.switchOffAutoHideShow();
      swfobject.embedSWF("main.swf", "ConnectDemo", "640", "480", "9.0", null, flashvars, null, {name:"ConnectDemo"});

    } else { //ask the user to login

      var params = window.location.toString().slice(window.location.toString().indexOf('?'));
      top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='+APP_ID+'&scope='+PERMS+'&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URI + params;
    }
  }
```

but the Name flashvars is showing up blank, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try using something other than Name (FbName), this could be a reserved property.

Comment: exact duplicate by same user of [Facebook pass username to flashvars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119357/facebook-pass-username-to-flashvars)

Answer (score 0):

FB.api() is asynchronous, so you need to wait to show the SWF until it has responded.

```
if (response.session) { //Show the SWF
    FB.api('/me/', function(response) {
        swfobject.switchOffAutoHideShow();
        swfobject.embedSWF("main.swf", "ConnectDemo", "640", "480", "9.0", null, flashvars, null, {name:response.name});
    });
}
```